# Better approach to check if a sentence is a palindrome in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I am new to Python (or programming rather) and am trying to learn recursion.

I have written a recursive python function to check if a sentence (not a word) is a palindrome or not.

```
def checkPalindrome(sentence):
    sentence = re.sub('[^\w]', '', sentence.lower())
    if len(sentence) == 1: 
        return True
    elif len(sentence) == 2:
        return sentence[0]  == sentence[1]
    else:
        return checkPalindrome(sentence[1:-1])
```

This function works and provides the correct result. Example:

```
checkPalindrome('Go hang a salami; I’m a lasagna hog')
True
```

However, since I am removing spaces, punctuations and changing the case of the sentence at the beginning of the function, this step would be computed at every recursive call.

Is there a better way to re-write the function to avoid this?

Comment: You could define a separate function that just "passes along" the lowercase, no-punctuation string. Or just start `sentence` as the correct value.

Comment: You're function won't work, for example pass in the string `"randomtextQQdsfdfdfs"` it will return `True` because you're checking for equality on the last two characters beside each other where the `QQ` characters makes this "palindrome" true

Comment: I think your logic is wrong here ... it will think its a palindrom as long as the two middle letters are the same (with an optional letter in the middle)... @Pythonista beat me to it

Comment: as such any function that actually checks if its a palindrome will be better at checking if its a palindrome

Comment: @Pythonista: I just checked `checkPalindrome('randomtextQQdsfdfdfs')` with the above code and it returned `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just answered your own issue: write one function to reduce the input to lower-case letters and call the second one.  This second function does the palindrome check and recursion.

However, note that your function doesn't work: the only time it checks the end characters against each other is in the base case of len(sentence) == 2.  You need to check just before your recursive call, too:

```
else:
    return sentence[0] == sentence[-1] and
           checkPalindrome(sentence[1:-1])
```

Given this, you could also combine your two base cases:

```
if len(sentence) <= 1:
    return True
```

---

Edited per @Joran's suggestion.  I've recently been living with too many compiler optimizations; my original is not guaranteed by the Python language definition; this update will work better in the general case.

Comment: good answer ... but it should probably be `return s[0] == s[-1] and checkPalindrome(s[1:-1])` at least my two cents, since there is no point checking the recursive palindrome part if the `s[0] != s[-1]` (+1)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I see how it needs to be done now.